# How to pass raw json string for aggregations in Search Request by calling SearchAsync in ElasticSearch NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a raw json string below to pass for aggregations in SearchRequest by calling SearchAsync  method.

```
"aggs": {
    "documents": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TypeField",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_t_hits": {
          "top_hits": {``
            "size": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
            {
                Size = 1,
                Aggregations =  "",
                Query = new QueryContainerDescriptor<dynamic>().Raw(queryjsonString)                   
            };
```

Can anybody help me on How to pass the above raw json string for Aggregations ?.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes I am able to pass raw query string using LowLevel.SearchAsync method of ElasticSearch.net but how do I get documents from Aggregations / Non aggregations response from the search result ?.  am calling as follows : var searchResult = await client.LowLevel.SearchAsync<T>(indexName, typeName, jsonQueryString);

Comment: I got it . I missed to specify SearchResponse<T>. Now am able to get documents from result.Body. So there is no way to pass raw json aggregation query other than using lowlevel.SearchAsync. am I correct ?.

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: There's an issue for this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1016

Comment: Thank you Russ for the link. one more question how do we specify all types if type name is empty (in my case) here as am getting exception when type goes empty. client.LowLevel.SearchAsync<T>(indexName, typeName, jsonQueryString);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127139/discussion-between-sasi-and-russ-cam).

Comment: use the `SearchAsync<T>(string index, PostData<object> body, Func<SearchRequestParameters, SearchRequestParameters> requestParameters = null)` method overload that doesn't specify type